# how to calculate performance of an index sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, indexing

I have a very large table that is currently at 700 million rows.  It is expected that this table will grow to 700 billion over time and my question relates to the design of this table and if it will continue to perform reasonably even at this size.

I would like to know how much will the performance of a query decrease when the table grows to 700 billion rows from the current level of 700 million rows?

The table is fairly simple with a single index on the table - below is the table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[datData](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Field_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [decimal](28, 10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The index is

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_datData] ON [dbo].[datData]
(
    [Field_ID] ASC,
    [Date] ASC
)
```

A typical query on this table is:

```
SELECT sum(d.value) 
    FROM datdata d 
    WHERE d.Field_ID = 21385 and d.Date > '1-Jan-2014' and d.Date < '1-Feb-2014'
```

Currently there are around 16,000 field IDs in the table, and the date field is sequential.  This makes a average of 43,750 records per field ID and I would expect this ratio to largely stay the same as the database grows to the 700 billion size.  This will mean that at 700 billion rows I would expect that we would have 16 million field IDs.

Although this growth is sometime away - I wanted to understand better if a serious bottle neck will occur and start to plan for database changes that may be needed as a result of these changes.

Comment: 43750 dates per fieldid = 120 years or is [Date] a timestamp? Also, why using an Identity if Field_ID+Date is unique?

Comment: is this only query you will use against the table?
what is the point of having ID column on the table
can you make another index xolumn in the table? what version of sql server you are using?

Comment: You will notice that the dates are datetime and the interval between consecutive dates can varry from 1 second to minutes. Most are seperated by 15 min. Also - you can have duplicate date entries for the same field_id, therefore the need for the ID column. SQL server version is currently 2012,but likely will upgrade to 2014 shortly. The queries varry, but always filter on Field_ID and Date.

Comment: Sorry - just looking again and it is possible that ID field is not needed as the index is unique clustered. I would note however this does not impact the question as I wanted some insight into the diff in performance between 700million and 700 billion rows. Is anyone able to assist with a answer to this question

Comment: I believe that the answer to this question may relate to the structure of a clusted index and the pages that are created - see this document (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835095(v=sql.110).aspx). maybe the size of the bTree and how much can be loaded into memory? Is this answer about memory, how much memory? How would the bTree look for the above index? Hoping someone can assist?

Answer (score 0):

In sql server management studio insert the query and select the option "Display estimated execution plan" to calculate performance of an index sql server.

that can give you large amount of information about the performance of your database, and the influence of created index on the performance, among other things.

more on the subject you can find here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx